# How do I install My custom character in project M?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

Okay. I have my brawl backup straight from my wii, my project M download, and my custom character. How do I install him without replacing anyone?

Comment: I think that, since Project M has very questionable legality and is more or less considered an "illegal mod/hack", the question doesn't fit under the community rules.

In any case, this is a Project M question, not a Brawl question.

Comment: @GarretJ, we only deem things illegal if they are actually illegal, much like how we dont immediately consider jailbreaking off topic.